# Using a ListFragment with a SimpleCursorAdapter with the Holder Pattern

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

I am implementing a `ListFragment` from a `ViewPager` and using a `ListAdapter` extending `SimpleCursorAdapter` and trying to keep the same Holder Pattern I was using before the conversion to using a `LoaderManager` with custom cursor and the `CommonsWare.loaderex` JAR.  Everything seems to be fitting together well except I placed the `LoaderManager` on the `ListFragment` and not in the `FragmentActivity` hosting the `ViewPager`.  Mostly because I was not sure about the required call backs to load / refresh the data in the list from the `FragmentActivity` and I wanted to avoid having a giant cursor out in memory since the overall form has many fields across all of the Fragments in the `ViewPager`.  It seemed okay to have each section of the form manage its own data in its own Loader.
When I build the Adapter Init setup similar to the demo project (see code snippet below)

```
private void initList() {
    getHelper();        
    adapter=new PhoneNumberListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.phonenumber_row, null, null, null);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, getActivity());   

}
```

The `getSupportLoaderManager()` flags as an error and I cannot figure out why.  Here is the full code for the Fragment (I know it’s a lame Phone Number Manager).  Any guidance on what I did wrong would be great.

```
package com.code.android.myproject

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.commonsware.cwac.loaderex.acl.SQLiteCursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import com.code.android.myproject.R;
import com.code.android.myproject.utilities.PhoneNumberListAdapter;
import com.code.android.myproject.data.AbstractDbAdapter;
import com.code.android.myproject.data.ActorDbAdapter;

public class ActorPhoneNumberListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
public final static String ID_EXTRA="com.code.android.myproject.actorid";
protected final static String TAG = "ActorPhoneNumberListFragment";
private SQLiteCursorLoader loader=null;
private PhoneNumberListAdapter adapter=null;
private ActorDbAdapter helper=null;
private String actorId = null;
//private SharedPreferences prefs=null;
OnActorPhoneNumberListListener listener=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    initList();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    helper.close();
    Log.w(TAG, "Closing database");

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (listener!=null) {
        int mId = Integer.parseInt(actorId);
        listener.onActorPhoneNumberListSelected(mId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contactlist_opton, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.addselected) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PersonForm.class));
        return(true);
    } else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.help) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), HelpPage.class));

        return(true);
    } else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.personRefresh) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PersonList.class));
        return(true);
} else 
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

public void setOnActorPhoneNumberListListener(OnActorPhoneNumberListListener listener) {
    this.listener=listener;
}

public void loadPhoneNumbers(String actorId) {
    this.actorId=actorId;

    if (actorId!=null) {
        initList();
    }
}

private void initList() {
    getHelper();        
    adapter=new PhoneNumberListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.phonenumber_row, null, null, null);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, getActivity());   

}

private void getHelper() {  
    if (helper==null) {
        helper=new ActorDbAdapter(getActivity());
        Log.w(TAG, "Creating a new instance of the database helper object");
    }
    helper.open();
    Log.w(TAG, "Opening database");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    helper.close();
}

public interface OnActorPhoneNumberListListener {
    void onActorPhoneNumberListSelected(long id);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    loader = new SQLiteCursorLoader(getActivity(), helper.mDb, AbstractDbAdapter.PHONE_VIEW, null);
    return (loader);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.changeCursor(cursor);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.changeCursor(null);

}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The getSupportLoaderManager() flags as an error and I cannot figure out why.

That is because there is no such method on `Fragment`. Call `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager()` to get your `LoaderManager`.

Comment: I added the `getActivity()` but I must really have this messed up because I am now getting the following message `The method initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>) in the type LoaderManager is not applicable for the arguments (int, null, FragmentActivity)`.

Comment: @ewjames: That is because your third parameter to `initLoader()` does not implement `LoaderCallbacks`. You implemented `LoaderCallbacks` on your `Fragment`; hence, pass the `Fragment` as the third parameter.

Comment: I did some checking while I was working on my edit and just changed my `initLoader(0,null,getActivity())` to `initLoader(0,null,this)` and then fixed my query and I got passed the error on but I am getting the infamous missing `_id` column.  I thought this restriction was not part of this method or is the `SimpleCursorAdapter` tripping me up here?

Comment: @ewjames: `_id` is a requirement of `CursorAdapter` and its subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll set things up following the `LoaderCustomSupport` example and that should work out for me.  I'll blog an example once I get it all working.